# Error on angular project: Can't bind to 'formGroup' since it isn't a known property of 'amplify-authenticator'

Tags: angular, aws-amplify

I am getting below error in my login form. Is there anything that I am missing?
`Can't bind to 'formGroup' since it isn't a known property of 'amplify-authenticator'`

Here is my code

auth component

```
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import { Component, OnInit, NgZone } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-auth',
  templateUrl: './auth.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./auth.component.scss']
})

export class AuthComponent {
  public loginForm: FormGroup;

  constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder ) {
    this.loginForm = formBuilder.group({
      email: ['', Validators.required],
      password: ['', Validators.required],
    });
  }
}
```

html

```
<amplify-authenticator [formGroup]="loginForm" >
</amplify-authenticator>
```

Here is my app module, where I have added amplify authenticator.
I have add the imports, however I am getting error. Please let me know if I have missed anything.

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { ServiceWorkerModule } from '@angular/service-worker';
import { environment } from '../environments/environment';
import { AmplifyAuthenticatorModule } from '@aws-amplify/ui-angular';
import { NotFoundComponent } from './not-found/not-found.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    NotFoundComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    AmplifyAuthenticatorModule,
    FormsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    ServiceWorkerModule.register('ngsw-worker.js', {
      enabled: environment.production,
      registrationStrategy: 'registerWhenStable:30000'
    })
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Answer (score 0):

As error messages says there is no `formGroup` property for `amplify-authenticator` component.

Did you mean `formFields`? But afaik this also does not take a `FormGroup` as parameter. Have a look at https://ui.docs.amplify.aws/angular/connected-components/authenticator/customization